# Calculating number of intersecting discs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

Please see this question and the accepted answer:

[Algorithm to calculate number of intersecting discs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801242/algorithm-to-calculate-number-of-intersecting-discs)

Instead of using a binary tree, what if you were to use an array, sort it and then simply iterate up through the array? Would it still be O(n log n)?

Iterating through the sorted array (to me) seems like it would be O(n^2)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer speaks about binary **search** over a sorted array, **not** about a binary **tree**. Binary search is `logn`, "simply iterating" is `n`. So you would make the solution `O(n^2)` indeed. But there is no point in simple iteration over an array that you know is sorted - you can use binary search.